# Javascript Running on JSFiddle but not on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Ok so I have a code that would show different forms based on dropdown selection
Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2J8b/) to that..

Well its always giving me Test1 which means its not changing the div display, it's working on JSFiddle but not on the webpage.. 
and here's my webpage markup

```
<html>
<body>

<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;   
}    

</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>

              document.getElementById('options').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};

             </script>
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="1"> Display </option>
  <option value="2">Wka</option>
</select>

<div id="1" class="hidden" style="display: block">Test 1</div>
<div id="2" class="hidden">Test 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because in the fiddle your code is set to run at `onLoad`, but in your code its running before the DOM is created.

Wrap your code into a `window.onload` event like this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('options').onchange = function() {
        var i = 1;
        var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
        while(myDiv) {
            myDiv.style.display = 'none';
            myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
        }
        document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
    };
};
```

Anyway, like @positivew remembered, your code misses the `<head>` tag. Is semantically correct to put your JS scripts inside it.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do when such problem comes `works in jsfiddle and not on webpage` is to see the source of the fiddle page.

Your source of the fiddle appears as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .hidden 
    {
    display: none;   
    }    

  </style>

  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById('options').onchange = function()
  {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) 
    {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
  };

   }//]]>  

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="options" id="options">
    <option value="1"> Test1 </option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    </select>

  <div id="1" class="hidden" style="display: block">Test 1</div>
  <div id="2" class="hidden">Test 2</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Paste the above code directly and it will work.

After pasting the code directly then you can remove unncecessary lines like below from the fiddle:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a onload function so your code is run after your HTML is loaded. Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('options').onchange = function () {
        var i = 1;
        var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
        while (myDiv) {
            myDiv.style.display = 'none';
            myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
        }
        document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
    };
}
```

You can also add the code after all your HTML, before the end of the body tag.

And note that in your post you are missing `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `<head>` tags.

Comment: This is true, but not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle is running your script [`.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FWindow.onload) of the `window` object, without you realizing it. This allows your script to pause on execution until the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

To have it work in your own environment, you can:

1. Place the entire script after the HTML you're trying to manipulate (e.g. end of the `<body>`)
2. Leave your code above the `<body>` and run it onload of the window object, e.g.

   ```
   window.onload = function () {
       document.getElementById('options').onchange = function () {
           var i = 1;
           var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
           while (myDiv) {
               myDiv.style.display = 'none';
               myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
           }
           document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
       };
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The page is loaded into the DOM from the top down.

Your `document.getElementById('options').onchange` is being called before the element with id `options` exists in the DOM.

If you put your script below the divs, it'll work because the divs are now there before the script is called.